# Compiling haml from a different directory

Tags: haml

I use this to launch my haml compile:

```
/install-location/haml /myproject/index.haml /myproject/index.html
```

It runs fine when I'm in the directory with the haml file but when I change to a different directory I get:

```
Exception on line 3: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - assets/page/structure/_head.haml
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you have some code in your Haml that is trying to read another Haml file, but is using relative paths. What does that portion of your code look like?

Comment: Line 3 is = Haml::Engine.new(File.read('assets/page/structure/_head.haml')).render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are trying to read — `assets/page/structure/_head.haml` is relative to the working directory, not to the source file directory. When you’re in the same directory it works because these two directories are the same.

To be able to run the code from a different directory you need to use absolute paths. You can convert the relative path to an absolute one with [`File::expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-expand_path), [`File::dirname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-dirname) and `__FILE__`:

```
= Haml::Engine.new(File.read(File.expand_path 'assets/page/structure/_head.haml', File.dirname(__FILE__))).render
```

Comment: This doesn't work when using, for example, guard-haml.